# fancytree filter node numeric name only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fancytree

I'm using [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) I have an issue with the filter **when a node name is only a number** like an image below

[image]

When I try to search for 700264 I got this error in the console and I have no idea if I do something wrong or if it is a bug

[image]

**Filter settings**

```
$("#treeMU").fancytree({
    extensions: ["filter"],
    quicksearch: true,
    checkbox: true,  // optional
    keyboard: true,  // Support keyboard navigation
    source: {
        url: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        
    },
    filter: {  // override default settings
       
        autoExpand: true,          // Expand all branches that contain matches while filtered
        counter: true,             // Show a badge with number of matching child nodes near parent icons
        hideExpandedCounter: true, // Hide counter badge if parent is expanded
        hideExpanders: true,       // Hide expanders if all child nodes are hidden by filter
        nodata: true,              // Display a 'no data' status node if result is empty
        mode: "hide"               // Grayout unmatched nodes (pass "hide" to remove unmatched node instead)
     
    },          
  });
```

**Search Input**

```
$("#TreeSearchMU").keypress(function(e){
   if(e.which == 13)  // the enter key code
   {
     $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#treeMU").filterBranches($("#TreeSearchMU").val());
   }  
  
});
```

When I try add any string character to node name (dot, comma, space, etc...) to be like

[image]

The filter is working fine with string character.

**Anyone knows what happened and why filter work with string character and does not work with a numeric name?**

##### Environment

- Browser type and version: Google Chrom Version 94.0.4606.61
- jQuery versions: 3.5.1
- Fancytree version: 2.38.0
  enabled/affected extensions: filter

Thanks for all.

Comment: Fancytree seems to assume that node.title is a string.  You might have better luck if you were able to stringify those numbers.

Comment: @James Yes I can stringify the number but there is no way to use it as it is

Comment: You should be able to transform the data you get from your API (change those numbers to strings) by adding a postProcess function, [tutorial link](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData#howto-handle-custom-data-formats)

Comment: I convert numbers in backend use strval() building method in php and it works